# Why did 0x swap API get deprecated and what is its substitute?

Tags: 0x, api, swap-api

[0x swap API](https://github.com/0xProject/0x-api) was a great project that was under active development for several years. But recently it got deprecated and no longer kept up to date. I could not find any other substitute for it on the 0x GitHub page and couldn't find out the [reason behind that decision](https://0x.org/post/0x-protocol-a-preview-of-whats-to-come), especially regarding the fact that the same API as a commercial service is still [offered](https://0x.org/pricing) by 0x team.
Does anybody know what is going on there? and is there any up-to-date substitute for the good old swap API?!

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to comment, so I will ask here:

Have you managed to find something else as a substitute? Anything you'd recommend?

Thanks in advance

Comment: unfortunately I could not find any substitute. They seem to be migrating toward a freemium plan for their swap API. Good free days of the Ethereum ecosystem are behind us!